# Yahoo Finance Web Crawler

Tags: python

I am writing a web crawler program to get the stock price of a company from Yahoo Finance.

```
import re
import urllib.request

stock = input('Enter a company to check its stock.')

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock) as urlfile:
    urltext = urlfile.read()
    stock_pattern = r'(\d+)\.(\d+)'
    for i in re.findall(stock_pattern, str(urlfile.read())):
        print(i)
```

How would I get the current stock price of a company? I suspect it should have something to do with the `for` loop.

Comment: Why would you do that when you can just [hit the API](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/GLD?region=US&lang=en-US&includePrePost=false&interval=2m&range=1d&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non API-Approach. Look into a library called Selenium. This will let you pick out a certain element (i.e. the current stock price).

here's an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='the file path of where you saved chrome driver')

browser.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock)
stockPrice = find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]')
print(stockPrice)
```

But yes, I would also follow the advice of the people in the comments and look into some finance website's api.